# looking for a way to upgrade / downgrade inside Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I need a way to upgrade/downgrade the `boto3` lib inside my Python 3.7 env inside Lambda.

Right now, the version is 1.9.42 inside Lambda. I cannot use certain things like Textract (`boto3.client('textract')`, but I can on my local machine (boto3 version 1.9.138.

So, I decided to install boto3 into a package (`pip3 install boto3 -t dir/ --system`) then upload it to Lambda after zipping it.

This didn't work because Lambda won't accept a package larger than 3MB (it's around 8MB)

Any other workarounds?

edit: I know I could always just write code that works and keep uploading it to Lambda, but this will become cumbersome as I'd have to include all the packages installed in the package and rebuilding it as I make changes.

Comment: The maximum compressed size is 50MB for AWS Lambda... the 3MB limit is only valid for the console editor, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: @jogold should've specified that I just want to use the inline editor

Comment: Using the console editor is good for testing/experimenting but not for real development. If your constraint is to keep using the console editor, I don't think there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [Serverless Application Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) is a tool provided by AWS that lets you develop locally as it simulates the lamdba environment inside a docker container. Once you are ready you can deploy your code to a lambda and it will work as expect.

If you really want to keep editing the code in the web platform, there is a workaround by using [lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). You create a package with all of your dependencies and upload that to a lambda layer. Then include your layer in the lambda and just modify your own code there. As it has been pointed out in the comments this is not the way to go for real development.

Comment: I've been looking into the layers currently, but will check out the SAM further. I'm having trouble importing my custom `boto3` layer into my code in the inline editor now.